# GCP endpoints and needed ports

Tags: go, networking, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google gcp go SDK (e.g. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/kms/apiv1#NewKeyManagementClient to initialize a KMS client). For security purposes I need to know exactly which endpoints and ports the google SDK is going to contact to communicate with GCP.

I can't find anything in the official documentation (only setup for on-premises through cloudVPC, which I think it's not what I need).

How can I find out the endpoints and ports needed for the cloud GCP SDK to communicate with the GCP platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endpoint is currently `cloudkms.googleapis.com:443`, unless configured explicitely. The fact that it's not documented means that it may change over time, without notice (although it is very unlikely that there will be no notice if it ever does change).

```golang
func defaultKeyManagementClientOptions() []option.ClientOption {
    return []option.ClientOption{
        option.WithEndpoint("cloudkms.googleapis.com:443"),
        option.WithGRPCDialOption(grpc.WithDisableServiceConfig()),
        option.WithScopes(DefaultAuthScopes()...),
        option.WithGRPCDialOption(grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(
            grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(math.MaxInt32))),
    }
}
```

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/af69f73/kms/apiv1/key_management_client.go#L66-L74

For up-to-date information query the discovery service at https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/cloudkms/v1/rest:

```
$ curl -s https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/cloudkms/v1/rest | jq -r .rootUrl
https://cloudkms.googleapis.com/
```

Comment: However, before contacting the KMS service, you will need an access token that you generate by calling this endpoint `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`. I recommend you to open egress traffic to `*.googleapis.com` on port 443 to avoid any side effect, or changes in the API behavior.